# dependencies in UML diagram

Tags: java, uml

In UML, if there's a class A having an object of type B as member, then A depends on B.
But I haven't understood if the dependency is valid even if A doesn't have any field of type B, but it uses an object of type B in it's method, for example:

```
public class A
{
    A()
    {}
    public void print()
    {
        B b=new B();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

This case, would it means that A depends on B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on what "depends" means.

In terms of Java, A depends on B when the code for A will not compile or run without B being present.

In terms of UML, "depends" is not a term that is used. If you for example have an arrow from class A to class B in a UML diagram, that means that A somehow knows about B. How that is implemented in the programming language of your choice depends.

**Warning:** Highly opinionated statement follows!

Avoid UML like the plague. Take it from someone who's worked with it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a dependnecy as `A` needs `B` in order to operate properly.  Also, if it has a member of type `B`, or if it inherits from `B`